# Submit Embedded Mailchimp Form with Javascript AJAX (not jQuery)

Tags: javascript, ajax, mailchimp

I have been trying to submit an embedded Mailchimp form with AJAX but without using jQuery. Clearly, I am not doing this properly, as I keep ending up on the "Come, Watson, come! The game is afoot." page :(

Any help with this would be **greatly** appreciate.

The `form action` has been altered to replace `post?u=` with `post-json?u=` and `&c=?` has been added to the end of the action string. Here is my js:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

    function formMailchimp() {

        var elForm         = document.getElementById('mc-embedded-subscribe-form'),
            elInputName    = document.getElementById('mce-NAME'),
            elInputEmail   = document.getElementById('mce-EMAIL'),
            strFormAction  = elForm.getAttribute('action');

        elForm.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {

            var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

            request.open('GET', strFormAction, true);
            request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=UTF-8');

            request.onload = function() {

                if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {

                    // Success!
                    var resp = JSON.parse(request.responseText);

                    request.send(resp);

                } else {

                    console.log('We reached our target server, but it returned an error');

                }

            };

            request.onerror = function() {
                console.log('There was a connection error of some sort');
            };

        });

    }

    formMailchimp();

});
```

Also, I anticipate the inevitable "why don't you just use jQuery" comment. Without going into the specifics of this project, jQuery is not something I am able to introduce into the code. Sorry, but this HAS to be vanilla javascript. Compatibility is for very modern browsers only.

Thanks so much for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 6):

A few days back I've had the exact same problem and as it turns out the **MailChimp** documentation on native **JavaScript** is pretty sparse. I can share with you my code I came up with. Hope you can build from here!

The simplified HTML form: I've got the from action from the MailChimp form builder and added "post-json"

```
<div id="newsletter">
    <form action="NAME.us1.list-manage.com/subscribe/post-json?u=XXXXXX&amp;id=XXXXXXX">
        <input class="email" type="email" value="Enter your email" required />
        <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Subscribe" />
    </form>
</div>
```

The JavaScript: The only way to avoid the cross-origin problem is to create a script and append it to the header. The callback occurs then on the “c” parameter. (Please note there is no email address validation on it yet)

```
function newsletterSubmitted(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    this._form = this.querySelector("form");
    this._action = this._form.getAttribute("action");
    this._input = this._form.querySelector("input.email").value;

    document.MC_callback = function(response) {

        if(response.result == "success") {
            // show success meassage

        } else {
            // show error message

        }
    }

    // generate script
    this._script = document.createElement("script");
    this._script.type = "text/javascript";
    this._script.src = this._action + "&c=document.MC_callback&EMAIL=" + this._input;

    // append script to head    
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(this._script);
}

var newsletter = document.querySelector("#newsletter")
newsletter.addEventListener("submit", newsletterSubmitted);
```

Comment: Hey @Hanslibuzli ! I've finally gotten around to trying out your code, but I am getting this error in the console: [ JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data ] ... pointing to this line: [ var ChimpResponse = JSON.parse(this.response); ] Interestingly, I do end up receiving a Confirmation email from Mailchimp. Any idea how to solve this problem? Thanks!

Comment: Hi @beefchimi I just updated my original answer - hope this helps!

Comment: I was trying this out and I know its been a few years...the POST doesn't work. This is the only thing I found for help on vanilla js ajax submission. I get the error `Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://localhost/NAME.us1.list-manage.com/subscribe/post-jso…8a3&id={removed}&c=document.MC_callback&EMAIL=test@test.com”.`

Comment: @Matt - I hope you sorted this out. You need to change the html code to `<form action = "https://ACCOUNTNAME.us11....etc` This will stop `localhost` from being prepended. ACCOUNTNAME is the name of your mailchimp account.